# Read file line by line and pass each value on intent

Tags: android

I need my code to read a file line by line, assign each of those values to different variables/strings and send it to another activity on intent.
The problem is, the file is being read and written like it's whole, here is part of the code.: (By the way I know I should make a method and call it inside my button click, will do that)

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), "resultado1");
            //Read text from file
            StringBuilder text1 = new StringBuilder();
            StringBuilder text2 = new StringBuilder();
            StringBuilder text3 = new StringBuilder();
            StringBuilder text4 = new StringBuilder();
            StringBuilder text5 = new StringBuilder();
            StringBuilder text6 = new StringBuilder();
            StringBuilder text7 = new StringBuilder();
            StringBuilder text8 = new StringBuilder();
            StringBuilder text9 = new StringBuilder();

            try {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                String line;

                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    text1.append(line);
                    text1.append('\n');
                    text2.append(line);
                    text2.append('\n');
                    text3.append(line);
                    text3.append('\n');
                    text4.append(line);
                    text4.append('\n');
                    text5.append(line);
                    text5.append('\n');
                    text6.append(line);
                    text6.append('\n');
                    text7.append(line);
                    text7.append('\n');
                    text8.append(line);
                    text8.append('\n');
                    text9.append(line);
                    text9.append('\n');
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e) {

            }
            Intent savedgame = new Intent(LoadSave.this, ResultSave.class);
            savedgame.putExtra("data", text1.toString());
            savedgame.putExtra("nomejogador1", text2.toString());
            savedgame.putExtra("pontosjogador1", text3.toString());
            savedgame.putExtra("nomejogador2", text4.toString());
            savedgame.putExtra("pontosjogador2", text5.toString());

            if (text6 == null) {

            }else{
                savedgame.putExtra("nomejogador3", text6.toString());
                savedgame.putExtra("pontosjogador3", text7.toString());
            }

            if (text8 == null) {

            }else{
                savedgame.putExtra("nomejogador4", text8.toString());
                savedgame.putExtra("pontosjogador4", text9.toString());
            }
            startActivity(savedgame);
        }


    });
```

So, let's say my file is written 1,2,3,4,5,6,7.. etc and commas represent lines, the output on my next activity whenever I try to use these values are always 1 2 3 4 5 6 7...etc altogether, I need to be able to set each of these strings to separate textviews on my next activity.
I think my problem is that I am assigning all the line values to a single "String line;" ? If it is I also don't know how to solve it...
And I am starting to learn about arrays, I don't know yet how to implement all these lines of code in a smaller array party, but I understand it would be much better, just please, try not to sugest that I should do that in array because I have not yet learnt that =)
If I missed some info just please let me know, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that in your code, you are appending each line read to *every* string. You need to separately copy each line to a different string.

You are appending every line in the file to every `StringBuilder`. Have you tried using an `array of Strings` instead?

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), "resultado1");
        //Read text from file
        String text[] = new String[9];

        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String line;

            for (int i = 0; (line = br.readLine()) != null; i++) {
                text[i] = new String(line) + "\n";
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {

        }
        Intent savedgame = new Intent(LoadSave.this, ResultSave.class);
        savedgame.putExtra("data", text[0].toString());
        savedgame.putExtra("nomejogador1", text[1].toString());
        savedgame.putExtra("pontosjogador1", text[2].toString());
        savedgame.putExtra("nomejogador2", text[3].toString());
        savedgame.putExtra("pontosjogador2", text[4].toString());

        if (text[5] == null) {

        }else{
            savedgame.putExtra("nomejogador3", text[5].toString());
            savedgame.putExtra("pontosjogador3", text[6].toString());
        }

        if (text[7] == null) {

        }else{
            savedgame.putExtra("nomejogador4", text[7].toString());
            savedgame.putExtra("pontosjogador4", text[8].toString());
        }
        startActivity(savedgame);
    }


});
```

It's more efficient to use the regular `String` class instead of `StringBuilder` if not too many operations are involved (In your case, a single append operation).

Even if you *have* to use `StringBuilder` reuse one instance; don't create individual instances for every string.

Also, your strings were indexed from 1. I have included the necessary changes, so that indexing starts from 0, which is the general convention. Staring index of 1 in case of arrays means you define one extra instance of the object, which is a waste of memory.

Comment: That looks very neat, as I said, I'm still learning about arrays, but that looked very simple. One thing, as you said, we are supposed to start at 0 for better memory usage, so it would be String text[] = new String[8]; instead of 9, right? since it's starting form 0, or am I thinking wrong?

Comment: The value you specify while declaring arrays is the number of elements. Here, the number of elements is 9 (index 0 to index 8).

Comment: Oh, yeah. Silly me, that makes perfect sense. I will test out the code and report how it does.

Comment: Okay that did the trick, it's partially working as it should, but the thing is, the numbers on the file are showing as 0 on the next activity. The file is like this.: First line date time, second line player name and third line player points and so on without date anymore. The player name shows normally, but the number values do not.

Comment: In `ResultSave.class`, are you using `getStringExtra` or `getIntExtra` to get the data?

Comment: I'm using Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); to get everything. On other activities I didn't have the same problem. And setting them or trying to like this text13.setText(string1 + " " + extras.getInt("pontosjogador1") + " " + string2); for example (Again my indexing crazy numbers).

Comment: The issue should be `extras.getInt("pontosjogador1")`. You see, everything read from the file is a `String`. `getInt` tries to retrieve a number.

Comment: Try using `extras.getString("pontosjogador1")` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your time man, that was the problem. I copied the getInt from another piece of my code and I forgot I was parsing string to the next activity. Thank you for all the help!